# Prolog need to get it fix

Tags: prolog, shortest-path

The solution

```
ppath(X,Y,M,Path,[Y|Path]) :- edge(X,Y,M), 

\+ memberchk(Y,Path).
path(X,Y,P,SoFar,Path) :- edge(X,W,M), \+ 

memberchk(W,SoFar),
    path(W,Y,N,[W|SoFar],Path), P is M+N.


pravilo(X,Y,Z) :-
    aggregate(min(W), P^path(X,Y,W,[],P), 

Z).
```

After that i am trying to use `?- pravilo(a,z,M).` get the result. but it says false.

My version SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 6.4.1)

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid assert/retract as far as possible.

Your graph has a loop between `f` and `g`, then you can't use the naive path/4 predicate, or your program will loop.

To avoid looping, you should invert the path construction (now it's 'bottom up'), to 'top down' adding a further argument (an accumulator) to path/4, and check that a node isn't already visited before recursing.

You can use memberchk for the test.

*edit*: here is the code

```
path(X,Y,M,Path,[Y|Path]) :- edge(X,Y,M), \+ memberchk(Y,Path).
path(X,Y,P,SoFar,Path) :- edge(X,W,M), \+ memberchk(W,SoFar),
    path(W,Y,N,[W|SoFar],Path), P is M+N.
```

this yields

```
?- path(a,z,W,[],P).
W = 27,
P = [z, e, j, b] ;
W = 26,
P = [z, g, b] ;
...
```

let's use library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) to complete the assignment:

```
pravilo(X,Y,Z) :-
    aggregate(min(W), P^path(X,Y,W,[],P), Z).
```

now I get

```
?- pravilo(a,z,M).
M = 24.
```

*edit* To get (full) ordered paths, these changes are necessary in recursion base

```
path(X,Y,M,Path,FullPath) :-
   edge(X,Y,M), \+ memberchk(Y,Path), reverse([Y|Path], FullPath).
```

and in top level predicate:

```
pravilo(X,Y,Z) :-
    aggregate(min(W), P^path(X,Y,W,[X],P), Z).
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. Can you please explain more to me? I am quite new to prolog.  I have problem with this statement "check that a node isn't already visited before recursing."

Comment: Let us assume this is a one way direction from a to z.  i try to apply this but still not get the result.  findall(X, path(a,X), List).

Comment: Hi Thank You So Much for Your Good Help! Can you provide the whole solutions? i am not sure why i always have the False error when i try to consult the code shows above.

Comment: That's the whole solution ! What Prolog are you using ?

Comment: Hi Just update the content. could you please take a look again? Thank you in many times

Comment: there is a typo on first rule: `ppath(X,Y,M,Path,[Y|Path])` should read `path(X,Y,M,Path,[Y|Path])`

Comment: Hi. Thanks. It is a full-width characters issue.  One more question that why the path displayed as [z, e, j, b] ? suppose should be like a,b,c,z. can you advice me ?

Comment: since your top level query only report the path' length, I skipped over that detail.

Comment: yes,understand that. But as the result displayed in the last part, can i insert any argument, to the system display the M and path together?  like M = 16  P = [a,b,c,z]

Comment: sure, but I think it's worth another question. If you find my answer useful, accept it and then go on refining your task....

Comment: Hi i have re-post it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045248/graph-path-define-issue  . can you please take a look again?  thank you